# RichEdit Text Font Changes Strangely

Tags: delphi, fonts, richedit

I am using Delphi XE3. I need to set some parts of a long statement to bold and red. Since TLabel does not support such a feature, while merge several TLabels is rather inconvenient, and [TJvHTLabel](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvHTLabel) does not support bold, I decide to implement that via a TRichEdit control, by setting:

1. BorderStyle to bsNone.
2. ParentColor to true.
3. ReadOnly to true.

Then use the following code to set 2 characters to bold:

```
  reMsg.SelStart := 2;
  reMsg.SelLength := 2;
  reMsg.SelAttributes.Style := [fsBold];
  reMsg.SelStart := 0;
  reMsg.SelLength := 0;
```

But I find the font of the rich edit control will changes to a strange one. Below is a comparison of the tlabel control and trichedit control:

[image]

You can see in the second caption, the font is changed.

I try many methods, such as set the font of the richedit control manually:

```
reMsg.Font.Name := labMsg.Font.Name;
reMsg.Font.Charset := labMsg.Font.Charset;
```

But still cannot solve the problem.

Why?

Comment: It seems like `FontPitch` property of  `reMsg.Font` is changed too... Did you try `reMsg.Font.Assign(labMsg.Font)`?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps, you should set your `TRichEdit`'s property `ParentFont` to true. In this case `TRichEdit` will use font of its parent (f.e. of `TForm`).
After this apply your code to make part of text bold and you will see this:

[image]

*On this image "is" in word "this" output with **bold** font style*

I didn't modify `Font` property neither of `TForm` nor `TRichEdit`. Just created new project and placed component on form. Because all work as expected, I suppose that the problem described in your question is related with manually modified `TRichEdit`'s `Font` property. Just get back default values of `TRichEdit`'s font or set its `ParentFont` property to `true`.

As an additional solution, instead of using `TRichEdit` for this purpose you'd better to look at `TMDLabel`.  It has lots of features to play with text style, color, size etc.

I don't know name of author of this nice component, but there is his web-site: [Infintuary.org](http://www.infintuary.org/stlabel.php)

For example, with this *pseudo-HTML-code* you can "paint" text as needed:

```
<fs:14><fc:clRed>This</fc> is a <fc:clBlue><b>test</b> caption</fc> for TLabel</fs>
```

After putting this text in `TMDLabel` you will get this (screenshot from demo-app downloaded from official web-site):

[image]

There is also demo-app which explains how to use this component and what tags it supports. Worth to try in my opinion.

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked. As you know, recommendation questions are off topic, and since this answer simply recommends a component, it stands to reason that it doesn't fit.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thank you! I've expanded my answer to explain what to do to avoid effect that OP observed.

Comment: Now the problem is that the behaviour reported in the question can't be reproduced. Which means the question should be closed rather than answered.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan does it a case not to answer if one can't reproduce described behaviour?

Comment: Of course. You can't answer a question that isn't well posed. If you do, expect down votes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I thought that any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful.

Comment: You could do that in comments. Answers are meant to focus on the question above all. If there is no well defined question there can be no answer.